# Web Font Malfunctions only in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, webfonts

I have installed a web font on my server, and when I view it in Firefox and IE, it is perfectly fine. Now when I open the same page in Google Chrome, the font isn't as I put it in the CSS! There are also other fonts on the site that display fine. It is just that one font not working. This was both tested with the local and the server copies, and neither worked.

The ***About Us*** is *Din*
And the content is *supposed* to be *Franklin Gothic*.

---

***Firefox:***

[image: Page section in Firefox browser]

---

***Internet Explorer:***

[image: Page Section in IE browser]

---

***Chrome:*** (*The one with problems*)

[image: Page section in Google Chrome browser.]

---

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
    src: url('Franklin Gothic.eot');
    src: url('Franklin Gothic.eot') format('eot'),
url('Franklin Gothic.woff') format('woff'),
url('Franklin Gothic.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('Franklin Gothic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks,
~BN

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP headers?  Chrome is picky about the mime type that's sent by the server.  I have an answer that may help you here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715962/is-it-ok-if-i-get-error-saying-that-fonts-arent-loaded-but-they-are-shown-on-th/12394229#12394229

Comment: @SteveWortham Nothing about the webfont.

Comment: The _Console_ of the _Chrome Dev Tools_ outputs nothing about the web font.

Comment: If the behavior is different for different fonts, then the issue apparently depends on the font. You need to tell more about them than just the relative URLs of the font files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the "*SVG declaration*" before the "*WOFF declaration*":

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic';
    src: url('Franklin Gothic.eot');
    src: url('Franklin Gothic.eot') format('eot'),
url('Franklin Gothic.svg') format('svg');
url('Franklin Gothic.woff') format('woff'),
url('Franklin Gothic.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No luck. It's still the same. :(